# Calling Gnosis safe's propose transaction (safeService.proposeTransaction) gives Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I Have followed the suggested answers for the same issue in [Getting ''Error: Unprocessable Entity" while calling 'safeService.proposeTransaction()'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120535/getting-error-unprocessable-entity-while-calling-safeservice-proposetransac).

Even after that, the issue is not solved. Please kindly help me.

The code is :

```js
import "./App.css";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import EthersAdapter from "@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SafeServiceClient from "@safe-global/safe-service-client";

import Safe, { SafeFactory } from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk";
import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types";

// require("dotenv").config();

// const gnosis = async () => {
//   console.log("Hello");
// };
const gnosis = async () => {
  // const txServiceUrl = "https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global";
  const safeAddress = "0xF05F8bc8a0D5FE5d2Eb2fB1d0F900b20E71dD966";

  // const {
  //   SafeFactory,
  //   SafeAccountConfig,
  //   ContractNetworksConfig,
  // } = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk");
  // const Safe = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk")["default"];

  // const EthersAdapter = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib")["default"];

  console.log("Hello");
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
  console.log({ provider });
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  const safeOwner = provider.getSigner();

  console.log("Meta mask address is ", safeOwner.getAddress(0));
  const address = await safeOwner.getAddress();
  console.log("ABC", address);

  const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider: safeOwner,
  });
  const txServiceUrl = "https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global";
  const safeService = new SafeServiceClient({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter });
  // const balances = await safeService.getBalances(safeAddress);
  // console.log(balances);
  const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress });
  const safeSdk2 = await safeSdk.connect({ ethAdapter, safeAddress });
  console.log("Please find the owners here", await safeSdk2.getOwners());
  const tocks = ethers.utils.getAddress(
    "0x1451Ec73259CCe92361f7Edb592DaEff947Df403"
  );
  const nonce = await safeService.getNextNonce(safeAddress);
  console.log("Nonce", nonce);
  const data1 = {
    to: tocks,
    data: "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000de7c0527b4b43bcbba09c4fbb8b9053156c23197000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a",
    value: 0,
    nonce: nonce,
  };
  const safeTransactionData = data1;
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
    safeTransactionData,
  });
  console.log(safeTransaction);
  const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
  // const signedSafeTransaction = await safeSdk.signTransaction(
  //   safeTransaction,
  //   "eth_sign"
  // );

  const senderSignature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash);
  console.log({ safeAddress }, 1);
  console.log("Safe Transaction", safeTransaction, 2);
  console.log({ safeTxHash }, 3);
  console.log({ address }, 4);
  console.log(senderSignature.data, 5);
  try {
    await safeService.proposeTransaction({
      safeAddress,
      safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
      safeTxHash,
      senderAddress: address,
      senderSignature: senderSignature.data,
      origin: "",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
  }

  console.log("Proposed transaction completed");
  // const txResponse = await safeSdk.approveTransactionHash(txHash);
  // await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
  // console.log({ signedSafeTransaction });
  const ownerAddresses = await safeSdk.getOwnersWhoApprovedTx(safeTxHash);
  console.log("All owners approved", ownerAddresses);
};
// 0x1451Ec73259CCe92361f7Edb592DaEff947Df403
// value : 0
// data : 0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000de7c0527b4b43bcbba09c4fbb8b9053156c23197000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
//        ; 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
// Nonce : 211

export default function App() {
  // const safeOwner = provider.getSigner(0);

  // const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  //   ethers,
  //   signerOrProvider: safeOwner,
  // });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <button onClick={gnosis}> Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set value as as a string. Like this:

```js
const data1 = {
  to: tocks,
  data: "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000de7c0527b4b43bcbba09c4fbb8b9053156c23197000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a",
  value: "0", // update this line
  nonce: nonce,
};
```